# css hide all the comment reply links except the lowest nested comments

Tags: comments, css

I understand different themes use different css for the reply link however there should be enough native WP css to narrow it down to the lowest nested comment.

I'm trying to get my head around the default WP comment css that will give me the ability to hide *display:none;* all the reply links except for the very bottom layer of the nested comments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to do that will be with javascript. Something that will navigate at each comment list and show only last button. Something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){

    //Hide all buttons
    $('.comments li .reply-button').hide(0);

    //Navigate through all comments
    $('.comments li').each( function() {

        //Lets check if there is children comments in this one
        if (! ($(this).children('.children').length > 0)) {

            //Don't have, so let's show this button
            $(this).find('.reply-button').show(0);
        }

    })
})
```

Comment: How/where would I use this?

Comment: In an script file or even outputting it directly in the sections comments

Comment: I added the snippet by following these instructions but it didn't work... https://wordpress.org/support/topic/howwhere-do-i-use-this-javascript-jquery-snippet?replies=4

Comment: Sorry about the late, this code is just a sample, you would still need to adapt it to your comments structure.